# Any in-game effects if you play Pokemon Go in another country?

Tags: pokemon-go

Does it have any in-game effects if you play Pokemon Go in another country? For example, if you catch Oddish in Hong Kong, is the Oddish you catch there different from a Oddish you catch in Tokyo (e.g. the country of catch is recorded on the data)?

Note that I do **NOT** mean whether you can play Pokemon Go in another country just using your home country's account; I ask if the data under it has any differences on playing among different countries, much like the 3DS games which show the birthplace (e.g. `USA` or `JPN`) and sometimes let you name in a  different way like Hangul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in Pokemon if you obtained it somewhere else.

When the game just launched, there was a map shown for each Pokemon where you had catch it. However, this feature has been removed as it was too stressful on the servers on Niantic, and might come back.